# Carport structure issues?

Tags: framing

Need your input: Questionable carport framing and spans.

It has an asphalt-shingled gabled roof with attic storage and an enclosed 7'deep workshop at the rear -  see photo.

Overall carport size is 20'8"'wide x 26' long. The 26' dimension includes the workshop, so the open span portion is 20'8" x 19'.

Roof rafters are 2x6 at 24"o.c. Ridge beam is 2x8 (attic clearance is 5.5' max). Joists: 2x10s at 24"o.c. and are parallel with the ridge beam (seems odd). Joists span 19'.

The contractor nailed 4' long 2x6s perpendicular to the outside joists to extend to the roof rafters (seems like a weak connection to roof structure).
Side Beams and front Beam are 2-2x12s. The joists go front to back (sit on front beam and workshop wall).  Attic floor is 3/4" plywood.

Beams supported by workshop wall and only 2 corner posts (4x6s!), which is a major concern for several reasons. Nails used - no hangers/ties.

Plan on storing usual household attic stuff.
Thoughts?
#1- Shorten Joist span: add an 8x8 trt post on each side with a 3ply beam side to side with metal connectors?
#2- replace the 4x6 posts with 8x8s.
#3 Improve connections: add Simpson connectors where possible?
But I need some more experienced input. And I don't know how to run load/span calculations.  I appreciate your help.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Before total freakout, "how old is it?" and "has it fallen down yet?" are things you should consider. You might [edit] in some pictures. You mention a photo but there's none here. When using the photo tool, (sun and mountains above the edit box) leave the text it inserts alone, so the photo will actually work.

Comment: The joists span the shorter distance, which is normal, and more important than which way the ridge beam runs relative to them.

Comment: Some pics of the actual framing might be useful...

Comment: Where is this? It does look like it might have trouble with wind loads from the side over the ridge causing high pressure on the upwind side and low pressure on the downwind side. Need diagonal braces at top. How are the 4x6 posts attached to the concrete? Are posts rotting at bottom? If a vehicle would take out a front post, then it would come down.

Comment: Could front beam be strengthened with a tension member on the bottom of the beam? Jack up center to remove sag then screw/nail heavy metal bands to bottoms of 2x12s?

Comment: I got structural drawings back.  4 new steel columns with new footings, and a new additional beam are in store.

Comment: Fortunately, there isn't any noticeable sag or movement.  But it is under supported for sure.  And only 2 outside posts are frightening.   It will be repaired propoerly soon.